# Objection.js : How to do an insert with all default values?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I am using Postgresql database. My ORM is objection.js ( with Knex). I am trying to insert a record with all default values like so in raw sql:

```
INSERT INTO public.myTable DEFAULT VALUES;
```

All these default values are defined already in the related schema, for all fields except ID (auto increment).

My question is, how to do this in Objection.js/knex??